# Is the Lebesgue integral essentially an inner measure of some kind?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider a non-negative Lebesgue-integrable function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a measure space, and let $F = \{(x,y)|x \in X, y \in [0,f(x)]\}$. Can the Lebesgue integral of $f$ be interpreted as $\eta(F)$, where $\eta$ is some sort of inner measure induced on the set $X \times \mathbb{R}$?

Rationale: When defining the Lebesgue-integral, one speaks of "horizontal strips" that are subsets of $F$. Thus, it looks like an inner measure.

Comment: Is it not the case that $\eta$ is in fact the product measure induced on $X\times\mathbb R$?

Comment: I dont know. I thinks its more like an inner measure....

Comment: Well, as @GregMartin mentioned it is indeed true that
$$
  \int_X f\mathrm d\mu = (\mu\otimes \lambda)(F) \tag{1}
$$
where $\lambda$ is a Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$. You can prove this fact by approximating $f$ with simple functions for which $(1)$ is the definition of the integral.

Comment: @Ilya That would imply that for all Lebesgue-integrable $f$, it holds that $F$ defined as above is necessarily an element of the domain of $\mu \otimes \lambda$. Are you sure this is true? A reference would be nice.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/measurable-graphs/